# expression between curly bracket with inside expression

Tags: java, regex

I have got example expression :

```
firstName =:'Mon';lastName =:'Arthur';:or{size >:'20';lastName ^:'H';:and{company |:'lon';:or{company |:'we'}}};lastName =:'aa';:and{length >:'33';:or{color =:'red'};width <:'2'};date <:'2012';:!{source =:'dictionary,locale'}
```

and regex must match:

1. :or{size >:'20';lastName ^:'H';:and{company |:'lon';:or{company |:'we'}}}
2. :and{length >:'33';:or{color =:'red'};width <:'2'}
3. :!{source =:'dictionary, locale'}

So that regex must match to expression that start with '`:[anycharacters]{`' and end with `'}'` and expression between that curly parentheses may also contains inner expression that can match.

I try to wrote something:
https://regex101.com/r/gM3dR9/13
and the return is:

1. :or{size >:'20';lastName ^:'H';:and{company |:'lon';:or{company |:'we'} - OK
2. :and{length >:'33';:or{color =:'red'} -MISSING `;width <:'2'}`
3. :!{source =:'dictionary, locale'}  -OK

Comment: What you are trying to do is not possible with regex. What is your language?

Comment: maybe try `;:(\S+(?:{.*?}(?=$|;[^}]*;:)))`

Comment: @SebastianProske Yea this is it :)

Comment: @SebastianProske. Please add your comment as an answer. This is really great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to work out a solution that fits your example and the requirements you wrote, but I'm not sure, if I got it entirely:

```
(?:;:)(\S+(?:{.*?}(?=[^}]*$|;[^}]*;:)))
```

This uses a positive lookahead to ensure that the last closing bracket is catched correctly (it has to be followed by the end of the string or another `;:`)

If it is possible, that your match is the beginning of the string and therefor not proceeded by `;:` you could change the part `(?:;:)` to `(?:^|;:)`

Here is the link for Regex101: https://regex101.com/r/dV8uI4/1

Answer (score 0):

Try this regEx

```
(:or{.*?\};{1,})|(:and{.*\};)|(:!{.*?\};{0,})
```

I can't guarantee for any other complex case, but it is definitely what you have mentioned as output **Except extra ';'**

```
"firstName =:'Mon';lastName =:'Arthur';:or{size >:'20';lastName ^:'H';:and{company |:'lon';:or{company |:'we'}}};lastName =:'aa';:and{length >:'33';:or{color =:'red'};:width <:'2'};date <:'2012';:!{source =:'dictionary,locale'}".match(/(:or{.*?\};{1,})|(:and{.*\};)|(:!{.*?\};{0,})/g)
```

**Output**

```
[":or{size >:'20';lastName ^:'H';:and{company |:'lon';:or{company |:'we'}}};", ":and{length >:'33';:or{color =:'red'};:width <:'2'};", ":!{source =:'dictionary,locale'}"]
```

**Formatted output**

```
[
":or{size >:'20';lastName ^:'H';:and{company |:'lon';:or{company |:'we'}}};",
":and{length >:'33';:or{color =:'red'};:width <:'2'};",
":!{source =:'dictionary,locale'}"
]
```

[**tested Here - Java RegEx Tester**](http://java-regex-tester.appspot.com/regex/94a27464-bc72-4b93-8700-0f813331f4e3)